# Beyond?? More or that and more?

Tags: meaning

If something is beyond, is it more than or that and more. For example the question i'm struggling with "Absences beyond 10 days". So is it 10 and more or 11,12,13 etc.

Comment: It's ambiguous, but I would interpret it as "Absences of *at least 11* days".  BUT the person who wrote *may* have meant "Absences of *at least **10*** days" - so the only cautious thing would be to ask the person who wrote it!

Answer (score 1):

Normal interpretation would be that a ten day absence would be an "absence **of** ten days" and that eleven or more would be an "absence **beyond** ten days". But if this is a rule you have to follow, you should check.

Comment: Of course, an absence of 10 days and 1 hour would be more than ten days.

Comment: I'd be inclined to think that, typically, any time *during* the tenth day would still not be considered beyond ten days. ("It's still day 10. They've got until day 11 before we take action.")